# Statistical Significance for Pairwise Ranking Algorithm

Tags: python, statistics, ranking

I am using this library: https://github.com/lucasmaystre/choix/blob/master/notebooks/intro-pairwise.ipynb

to rank items that have been rated in a hot-or-not style. For example, two images are shown to users and the user picks the one that appeals most to him/her. The final output is a ranking: worst to best: image1 image5 image3 etc.

The algorithm is using a Bradley-Terry model on this data. choix provides several algorithms and uses a maximum-likelihood inference algorithm called I-LSR.

However, I do not know the statistical significance of the ranking. How do I figure out if this ranking is statistically significant?

Comment: I found this out: The BradleyTerry-Luce
model computes a p-value that express how the
visualizations compare to one specific visualization only,
which serves as reference and is a parameter of the formula.
Thus you need to perform additional to tests for  for each comparison. To counteract the problem of making multiple comparisons tests you use a Bonferroni
correction